# Update content of one column of sql table from another column of same table

Tags: sql

Structure is like:

```
Col1        Col2
12345       12  
12348       14
20145       16
00541       13
51234       22
```

I want to copy col2 elements from col1 elements. 
What is query to do that?

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is for Col2 to equal Col1 then you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE aTable
set Col2 = Col1
```

Comment: will all elements of col2 be as same of respective data of col1?

Comment: so your first column of 12345, 12 would read 12345,12345 and the second 12348, 12348 and so on.